# create vpn connection with a preset credential using DotRas

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, visual-c++, vpn

I am using DotRas to automate VPN creation
https://dotras.codeplex.com/

everything works fine, except that newly created vpn connection does not remember credential i programmed in application. notice the checkbox for Remember my credential [image: options]
DotRas seems have all options for Vpn connection, but i cant find how to preset this checkbox

anyone knows how to make it remember credential?

Comment: Really, which language are you targeting? Because I doubt you are working in VB.NET, C# and C++ at the same time.

Comment: well, i tried c# and vb, but this is not related to languages, it has to do with API i think, i simply don't see any options there. maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
VpnEntry.Options.CacheCredentials = true;
```